# How do I fill a handsontable from a javafx WebView using a JSObject?

Tags: webview, javafx, handsontable, jsobject

I try to use the api method `loadData (data: Array)`.
The handsontable has two text columns.

I get the `JSObject` calling:

```
JSObject jsTable = (JSObject) webView.getEngine().
executeScript("$('#example').handsontable('getInstance')");
```

I construct the data array like this:

```
Object[] data = new Object[]{
    new Object[]{"s1", "s2"},
    new Object[]{"s3", "s4"}};
```

And call:

```
 jsTable.call("loadData", data);
```

But get a `*netscape.javascript.JSException: RangeError: Range error*` exception.

What am I missing?

Later edit: The following, which sets the content of a single cell, works.

```
Object[] params = {0, 0, "s1"};
jsTable.call("setDataAtCell", params)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `data` to followig instead:

```
var data = [
    ["s1", "s2"],
    ["s3", "s4"]
];
```

For more details on datasources see here:

http://handsontable.com/demo/datasources.html

Comment: Remember I have to create the object in java and pass it to javascript.